# The request response was returned in $kernel->handle($request)

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

this is code from laravel API `public/index.php` file.

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

When sending a request it returns without any data and with `status code: 200` just from `$kernel->handle`.

When I print `dd('111');` before

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

it is shown in request's reponse, but when I print after `$response = $kernel->handle()`, the request has no response.

Comment: when you print what after `$kernel->handle()`? and you mean it isn't in the `$response` ... well that would make sense since that `$response` is the built response object ready to go so you printing something isn't going to add to it

Comment: How would `$kernel->handle(...)` ever get reached if you `dd` before it? dd = dump and die. `die` is equivalent to `exit`.

Comment: I mean that the response is returned inside the `$response = $kernel->handle(...)` and not after it.

Comment: what "response" are you talking about? `$response` is the Response ... and why are you doing any of this?

Comment: `Route::get('/calendar','OptionController@getCalendar')` is my request route. when I send `/calendar` request it has no response data. even if I delete that route line, I have no error, just `status code:200` and no response data

Comment: are you actually returning something from that Controller method? are your routes cached?

Comment: yes, but the request not reaching to Controller method. even if I delete all my routes and functions inside `OptionController` I have 200 status code with no response.

Comment: @TakhtakTeam I think you should check all of your controllers and make sure there are no spaces in front of the `<?php` tag. The `<?php` tag should be the very first thing in the file.

Comment: the issue is connected to the domains or something like that. Because when I put the same request from the production API server, it fails again. But that request gives me the right response on the production application

Comment: @Takhtak Team You said: 'if I delete all my routes and functions inside OptionController I have 200 status code with no response.' So, I think there are spaces lines before '<?php' tag. Could you please check again all your files?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG Thanks but as I said there aren't any spaces. Requests to `https://option.productionapi.com/` from 'https://production.liveapp.com/' returns the response, but request to 'https://option.productionapi.com/' from 'https://developer.liveapp.com/' isn't.

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same issue - empty response with 200 http status. Adding breakpoints showed that it couldn't get past the `$kernel->handle()` call in the *index.php*.

Turns out it was caused by whitespace in my .env file

```
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Test Instance
```

should have been enclosed in quote marks

```
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Test Instance"
```

Answer (score 5):

Install libapache mod

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php8.x
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you!